# AngularJS $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a user profile page. Where User can display and edit their information.

This is my Controller.js

```js
var userProfileControllers = angular.module("userProfileControllers", []);

userProfileControllers.controller ('userProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'localCache', 'customersignup', function ($scope, $location, localCache, customersignup){

 var submitProfile = function() {


 //Bind Scope
 //
 var bindScope = function () {
     $scope.userProfile = customersignup.userProfile; 
 };

 var asyncBindScope = function() {
  $scope.$evalAsync(bindScope());
 };

 bindScope ();

 
}}]);
```

This is my service.js

```js
var userProfileServices = angular.module("userProfileServices", []);

userProfileServices.factory("customersignup", function() {
  return {
    userProfile: {fname: "kunal"},

    updateProfile: function() {
      var userProfile = this.userProfile;
 
    },

  }
   
});
```

In the HTML, let's say in case of first name I have included ng-model="userProfile.fname" in the input of First Name field. Now, when I am loading the html page, I am getting this error :- 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=localCacheProvider%20%3C-%20localCache%20%3C-%20userProfileCtrl

Please check the above link, it is from AngularJS official site.

Comment: localCache has some problem .Either you have not created it or missed to inject in controller..

Comment: where is the localCache ?

Comment: After this line var `userProfileControllers = angular.module("userProfileControllers", []);`  Why do you need of this line  `var userProfileServices = angular.module("userProfileServices", []);` ?

Comment: Try @vineet OR K.Toress answers

Answer (score 3):

check you have two modules one is for `service` and other one is for `controller`, and note that there is no glue between these two modules, to work this you need to glue these two modules, to do that, import the service module in to controller module as below.

```
var userProfileControllers = angular.module("userProfileControllers", ['userProfileServices']);
```

then module `userProfileControllers` have access to module `userProfileServices` which service is defined. Other vice you don't have access to service module `userProfileServices`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add factory name in controller `userProfileServices`